# Wildcard SSL cert installation on IIS7

Tags: ssl, windows, iis, wildcard

My wildcard cert (using SSL.com cert) has subject *.site.com, but for some reason it only works on the first site it's installed on and not the other sites on the server. Those other sites just point to the first site when using https even though each has a unique ip address.

I have the wild card certificate installed on IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2. I need to install it on ~30 subdomains with each having a unique ip address.

Comment: What do you mean "it only works on the first site"? What kind of problems are you seeing?

Comment: The sites work indivually, but when SSL is activated using https in the browser, the site that appears is the first site I setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the certificate. You've either screwed up the site bindings (you did bind to an address and not *All Unassigned* right?) or you have a DNS or URL Rewrite problem.

Comment: Yeah that was it, each site's address:443 was set to the same as the original site's address:443, although they each had their address:80 as a unique ip address. Very strange, but we got it working. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score -1):

I just checked the details provided on ssl.com wildcard certificate page *ssl.com/certificates/wildcard*

They did not mention that the certificate can install on multiple servers too.

I am sure this certificate can fulfill your requirements.

Comment: I already bought my certificate, and it's for a single server so I don't know how your answer relates to my question.